# Eee PC 900 dies quickly regardless of battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure, battery, eee-pc

I received an old Eee PC 900. It works fine, except the battery charges and discharges really quickly (under an hour).

I thought this was an issue with the battery, so I bought a new one with about twice the capacity. It did not fix the problem. I tested the charger - it outputs 12.3V, which seems fine, as the label says "12V". I also tried charging for much longer, past 100%, but nothing changed.

Is there anything I can do other than replacing the entire motherboard?

Comment: I assume the device has never properly worked while you had it?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the issue has been there since day one. Also, the previous owner had the device connected to the charger at all times.

Comment: Let me guess the replacement battery is a generic battery from an unknown manufacture?

Comment: @Ramhound Well... yes. It doesn't have the Eee PC series logo on it, unlike the original battery.

Comment: Two options: Second battery is also bad, or the motherboard has a problem and is incapable of charging it.